# Calling javascript ahead of response.redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to restrict an unauthorized user from accessing a `Utilities.aspx` page and redirect him to `Default.aspx` page.

```
if (authorizedUser.ToLower() != "admin")
{
    if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("UnauthorizedUserRedirect"))
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "UnauthorizedUserRedirect", "<script>alert('Unauthorized access!\n\nYou have attempted to access a page that you are not authorized to view.')</script>", true);
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

However, while the redirect is working fine, the `alert` is not showing up on the page. Searching for this issue tells me that Response.Redirect completes its action before the client side code is rendered at all.

How can I display the `alert` before the `Response.Redirect`?

---

I also tried these two approaches in `Page_Load` of `Default.aspx` and both didn't work. If a certain session bariable is set, then display the alert.

```
if (Session["unauth"] != null)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "UnauthorizedUserRedirect", "alert('Unauthorized access!\n\nYou have attempted to access a page that you are not authorized to view.');", true);
}


if (Session["unauth"] != null)
{
    form1.Attributes.Add("OnLoad", "javascript:alert('Unauthorized access!\n\nYou have attempted to access a page that you are not authorized to view.');");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use HTTP redirect + javascript. If you want to show an alert messaje before redirecting, you'll need to use a 100% javascript solution, generating a big security hole that could easily cause unauthorized accesss to that page.

I'd say the best you can do is showing a descriptive message on target page. You could send a querystring parameter for this.

Comment: Or set a session variable, to avoid tampering with the querystring. But the general idea is so far the best among the answers.

Comment: @Renan: session could be used too. In any case, take into account that I'm not talking about sending any sensitive information trough querystring.

Comment: I know. It's just that I've done that once, for a college site. The querystring had the text that would be displayed in an alert after logging out. Students kept sending each other links to the logout page with messages like "you have been logged out because fat people are not allowed in here" and such (minified links, of course).

Comment: I realized that the best possible thing is to show some message on the target page. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Redirects are an HTTP feature; performing a redirect skips your page entirely.

Instead, you can use more Javascript to perform a client-side redirect after the alert.
Specifically, set `location.href`.

Comment: Which the browser may block. Mine specifically always pops up a confirm asking whether I wish to be taken where the script is trying to lead me, and I mostly always say "no".

Comment: @Renan: I've never seen a browser do that.  What browser are you using?

Comment: I use FireFox and Chrome. There are extensions and plugins that allow the user to fine tune the way he wants to deal with redirects.

Answer (score 3):

[`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is setting a [`Location`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) header which the browser sees and runs with before it sees any content on the page. If you want the page to actually execute you'd have to allow them to get to the page first and not just redirect them.

Example:

Client Request:

```
GET /Utilities.aspx HTTP/1.0
Host: www.somehost.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (Windows XP)
Accept: text/html, */*
```

Server Response:

```
HTTP 300 OK
Location: /SomeNewPage.aspx      <-- Browser see this and goes
Content-Length: 12345

<html>                           <-- ignores from here down
  ...
  <script>alert('You\'re being redirected');</script>
  ...
</html>
```

Client New Request:

```
GET /SomeNewPage.aspx HTTP/1.0
Host: www.somehost.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (Windows XP)
Accept: text/html, */*
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm with @ClaudioRedi on this one. The only way to do that is via JavaScript, in ways that:

- May be blocked by the browser, even if JavaScript is enabled;
- Will surely open a security hole.

My suggestion is that you have that alert show after loading the landing page.

Comment: I've never seen a browser block this, and this will not open a security hole (unless you under-escape the string)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "", script,true);
```

Not

```
this.GetType()
```

but

```
Page.GetType()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Redirect, You can try like this :-

```
 System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
                sb.Append("alert('hello');window.location.href=\"page2.aspx\"");
                sb.Append("</script>");

 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "anything", sb.ToString(), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Client side redirect to another page.

```
if (authorizedUser.ToLower() != "admin")
    {
        if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("UnauthorizedUserRedirect"))
        {
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "UnauthorizedUserRedirect", "alert('Unauthorized access!\n\nYou have attempted to access a page that you are not authorized to view.'); window.location.href = 'Default.aspx';", true);

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
in javascript function after alert add

```
top.location='default.aspx';
```

now your code like

```
if (authorizedUser.ToLower() != "admin")
{
    if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("UnauthorizedUserRedirect"))
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "UnauthorizedUserRedirect", "<script>alert('Unauthorized access!\n\nYou have attempted to access a page that you are not authorized to view.');top.location='Default.aspx';</script>", true);

    }
}
```